# RabbitMQ RPC using Node.js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, rpc

I use RabbitMQ to implement RPC in Node.js.

I follow the tutorial, I assert the same name of queue for every client as 'rpc_client' in order to be high-authority,here is the `client.js` to call the function in the server:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

async function client(){
    let args = process.argv.slice(2);
    let corr = generateUuid();
    let num = parseInt(args[0]);
    try {
        let conn = await amqp.connect('amqp://127.0.0.1');
        let ch = await conn.createChannel();
        let q = await ch.assertQueue('rpc_client');

        console.log(' [x] Requesting fib(%d)', num);
        console.log(q.queue)

        await ch.consume(q.queue,msg=>{
            if (msg.properties.correlationId == corr) {
                console.log(' [.] Got %s', msg.content.toString());
                ch.ack(msg)
                setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 5500);
            }
        },{noAck:false});

        ch.sendToQueue('rpc_server',
        new Buffer(num.toString()),
        { correlationId: corr, replyTo: q.queue });

    } catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
}

function generateUuid() {
    return Math.random().toString() +
           Math.random().toString() +
           Math.random().toString();
}

client();
```

but I found when I run several clients at a time, the latter client will not run the consume callback (get answer from the server and print it) until the former client's connection has been closed. e.g. The second client will get the answer and print it and its connection will closed in 5500 ms, and the second one has to wait the first one to close and it will print the answer then wait another 5500 ms to close.

So why shoud this be? since the queue can consume the two massages in two worker parallelly.

and here is the `server.js`:

```
async function server(){
    try {
        let conn = await amqp.connect('amqp://127.0.0.1');
        let ch = await conn.createChannel();
        process.once('SIGINT',()=>conn.close());

        let q = await ch.assertQueue('rpc_server');
        ch.prefetch(1);
        console.log(' [x] Awaiting RPC requests');

        await ch.consume(q.queue,msg=>{
            let n = parseInt(msg.content.toString());

            console.log(" [.] fib(%d)", n);

            let r = fibonacci(n);

            ch.sendToQueue(msg.properties.replyTo,
            new Buffer(r.toString()),
            {correlationId: msg.properties.correlationId});

            ch.ack(msg);
        },{noAck:false});


    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

server();

function fibonacci (n , ac1 = 1 , ac2 = 1) {
    if( n <= 1 ) {return ac2};

    return fibonacci (n - 1, ac2, ac1 + ac2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the queue name is same, then it's the same queue. Not two queues with same names. In this case it makes sense that the clients are getting messages sequentially and not parallely.

So try with different queue names and it should work.

Comment: but why the servers with the same queue can run parallely? refer to http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html

Comment: Multiple consumers an subscribe to same queue. In that case, they will receive alternate messages. Like the odd ones will go o first consumer, and then even ones to second. More details of this pattern are available here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html

Comment: that's right, so the question of mine, there are two clients, they call the function in server, then the server will produce two massages back to `rpc_client` queue, so the two clients can deal with them parallely. But they didn't, why?

Comment: @laoqiren i have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you have to change the prefetch to a number greater than 1.

> basic.qos (prefetch) method to allow you to limit the number of unacknowledged
>   messages on a channel (or connection) when consuming.

so the problem is with this parameter. your channel will wait until your first request is processed and acknowledged.